# Php file upload always empty

Tags: php, html, file-upload, is-empty

Always when I upload a file the result is empty.
The code is from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).

The index.html file:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The upload_file.php:

```
<?php
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES['file']['name'] . "<br>";
?>
```

The result is:

> Upload:

I configure my php.ini, too enable file_upload, memory 5000M, and tmp location.

I don't know it maters but I use Ubuntu.

The result of phpinfo is as I configure.

What's wrong? Thanks!

print_r is show Array ()

echo $_FILES['userfile']['error'];

```
HP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/msql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/msql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
    [Wed Mar 05 17:48:16 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Wed Mar 05 17:50:05 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
    [Wed Mar 05 17:50:05 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/404.html
    [Wed Mar 05 17:55:32 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file in /var/www/uploadart.php on line 2, referer: http://localhost/index.php
```

At my original file error log is empty.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Apache after changing your php.ini settings?

Comment: About 3 times. I tried that.

Comment: Show us the ouput of `print_r($_FILES);` like @OneOfOne suggested.

Comment: print_r is not showing enything just Array()

Comment: If that is your entire code, you are missing [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) <= do read the manual. @user3369031 - Amongst other things. That single line of code won't upload anything. If it isn't your full code, then do post it.

Comment: if i tried that same result:nothing :( Befoure uploading i want to be shure that is work. Is my entire code

Comment: Show me your actual working code in an edit. And are you running this from your own computer (localhost) or on a hosted website? @user3369031 Plus the code you say that you took from W3Schools is not at all the same as you posted in your question. There's a LOT of stuff missing.

Comment: That is the wotking code and the entire. Is host in my Ubuntu PC.

Comment: You said your upload tmp directory is `/var/www/test/tmp` check that this path exists and that it is CHMOD to 777

Comment: All /var/www/test is set at 777

Comment: You must have included a script which handles form posts that could get in conflict with file uploads. I had a similar problem and fixed it by removing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Always when I upload a file the result is empty. The code is from [`here`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)."*

The code you say that you took from W3Schools is not what you posted for code and that you mention the code you are using is only:

```
<?php
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES['file']['name'] . "<br>";
?>
```

What W3Schools has on their page (from the link you provided), is the following:

HTML form:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
?>
```

Yet this is missing the most important component [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file)

which is included further down the page under **Saving the Uploaded File** and is as follows: (assuming you want to only allow `("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png")` in the array.

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Now, you need to create a folder called `upload` and then run the form and PHP from your root and make sure that the folder exists and has proper write permissions.

Comment: Invalid file all the time. move_uploaded_file() is change the file location not modify the output of $_FILES['file']['name'] witch is null. In the tmp folder is nothing.

Comment: Are you running the form and have the PHP in the root (and not in a sub-folder), and does the `upload` folder exist with proper write permissions? @user3369031 and did you copy everything exactly from my answer?

Comment: All yes. I triple checked everything befoure open this topic.

Comment: I remember seeing another question a week or so ago, about a similar problem where the OP was running it from Ubuntu server and had to change the folder permissions elsewhere and I can't remember what it was exactly. It's most likely the same thing happening. @user3369031

Comment: That ask was not on stackoverflow. I fix it and i started another project. It was not a bit asame i had a ftp that deny me to have 777 at /var/www/.

Comment: I didn't mean that "you" posted a question, I meant that I saw someone else post a question with a similar problem. @user3369031

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. The problem must be with configuration on your server. Check this lines in php.ini:
*file_uploads, upload_max_filesize, upload_tmp_dir, post_max_size, max_input_time*


You can also echo this line:

```
$_FILES['userfile']['error']
```

Comment: As in your list: on, 5000M, /var/www/test/tmp, 8M, 60. And the code is return nothing.

Comment: You just copied $_FILES['userfile']['error'] or used $_FILES['file']['error'] also, did you checked error logs?

Comment: Both, and both return null. On error logs have lots but i dont know what they mean. Posted up.